# Sharepoint/Get Document Set Properties using Rest

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest

I created a document set with properties like 'name and description' as string , 'cover photo' as href.

Each document set contains folders inside.
I can get the name of the folders inside the document set using

`/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRealtiveUrl('/Document')?$expand=Folders,Files`

Now I'm trying to get the document set properties (like the Name and cover Photo).
I tried the

`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('docset')/Items` 
but i get all the files inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

the solution should be add

```
?$expand=Folders,Files,ListItemAllFields
```

at the end of the endpoint.

:D

Comment: Thank You So Much, I had to add ListItemAllFields/MyProperty